# Local storage is not shared between different tabs

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, local-storage, microsoft-edge

I have a website which is used in **iframe**. We can call it https://example.com
I set an item to local storage in the **iframe** context so that we see newly added item in the origin https://example.com.

After that we **redirect** to new URL using `window.location.replace` functionality. This new URL opens in a new **tab** so it is no more in the **iframe** context, but the **origin** is still the same.

In the new tab we can't see the value in the local storage anymore that we set in the **iframe** context. I was able to fix this problem in firefox by disabling Enhanced Tracking Protection and selecting Custom with Cookies as Cross-site tracking cookies. I tested different settings for Microsoft Edge and goggle chrome also but was not able to find the fix.

Help would be appreciated if this problem can be fixed for the mentioned browser also or no i need to change the code to handle the data different way for example `window.postMessage`

Comment: Basically, the local storage can be shared between different tabs with the same origin. My tests have confirmed this. I tried opening a new tab using `window.location.replace`, but it is still in the current tab. How do you open a new URL in a new tab? Could you please provide a code snippet to help us reproduce the issue?